# Сделал калькулято, но не могу понять как в мой код вставить правильно проверку деления на ноль. Подобной конструкции не находил на просторах интернета

Tags: java, java-8

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int operand1 ;
        int operand2;

        System.out.print("Введите первое число");
        operand1  = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Введите второе число");
        operand2 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Что делаем(+-*/)?");

        String sign = scan.next(); // + - * /

        switch(sign) {
            case "+":
                System.out.println(+(operand1 + operand2));
                break;

            case "-":
                System.out.println(+(operand1  - operand2));
                break;

            case "*":
                System.out.println(+(operand1  * operand2));
                break;

            case "/":
                System.out.println(+(operand1 / operand2));
            {
                if (operand2 == 0) ;
                System.out.println("Ошибочка у тебя вышла");
            }
                break;

            default: {
                System.out.println("Неверная операция");
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: На находил значит не искал. Ну и проверку на ноль надо делать перед делением, а не после  И там лишняя точка с запятой

Answer (score 2):

Измените блок `case "/"` на:

```
case "/":
    if (operand2 == 0)
        System.out.println("Ошибочка у тебя вышла");
    else
        System.out.println(+(operand1 / operand2));
    break;
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Так как сначала нужно проверить не является ли делитель нулем, измените `case "/":` на:

```
 case "/":
                if (operand2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Ошибочка у тебя вышла");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.println((operand1 / operand2));
            break;
```